# Событие  xhr.onprogress срабатывает один раз

Tags: ajax, javascript

Почему событие  `xhr.onprogress` срабатывает один раз?

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();    
var data = new FormData(createGeneralEl.form);

data.append('image', fileL);
xhr.open("POST", '../www/s.php')
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
xhr.send(data);

console.log(xhr)
xhr.onprogress = function(e){
    console.log(e.loaded)
}

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        //...
    }
}; 
})(file)
```

Comment: Если на localhost, то это нормально, + xhr.send нужно разместить в конеце.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем тут играет важную роль размещение

```
                xhr.send(data);
```

---

```
          (function getMicroImg(fileL){ 
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
                var data = new FormData(); 
                data.append('image', fileL); 
                xhr.open('POST', '../www/s.php');

                if (xhr.upload) {

                    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
                        if (e.lengthComputable) {
                            console.log(e.loaded)
                        }
                    },false);

                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { 
                           //...
                        }
                    };

                    xhr.upload.addEventListener('load',function(e){},false);
                    xhr.upload.addEventListener('error',function(e) {},false);
                }

                xhr.send(data);

            })(file)
```